# How to convert Future to Uni?

Tags: java, vert.x, quarkus, mutiny

I have a Java API that returns a `Future` instance. I need to convert it to a `Uni`.
From the mutiny documentation, I see [it is possible to convert a `CompletionStage` to `Uni`](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides/completion-stages#creating-a-uni-from-a-completionstage), but I couldn't find how to convert a standard `Future` to `Uni`.

**Q:** How to convert `java.util.concurrent.Future` to `Uni`?

I understand that I can warp it's `get()` call to `Uni`, but it would be blocking, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with `Future` is that it's a blocking API and, unlike `CompletionStage`, there is no way to chain a stream of operations.

However, Mutiny has [a way to deal with blocking API](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides/imperative-to-reactive#running-blocking-code-on-subscription):

```
Future future = ...;
Uni<Object> uni = Uni.createFrom()
    .item( () -> future.get() )
    .runSubscriptionOn( Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool() );
```

**UPDATE:**

My answer will work for all blocking code but the correct answer is in the comments:

```
Uni.createFrom().future(future);
```

or

```
Uni.createFrom().future(() -> future))
```

Comment: Thank you. But how does it answer my question?

Comment: Sorry... It was late and I was thinking about `CompletableFuture` and not `Future`. I will update the answer :)

Comment: You can use `Uni.createFrom().future(future)` or `Uni.createFrom().future(() -> future))`

Comment: Related, if you have a vert.x Future: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73631825/java-how-to-uni-createfrom-future-and-return-that-uni-from-the-enclosing-met